# How can I provide inputs to a java application during run-time, through netbeans window?

Tags: java, netbeans

How can I provide inputs to a java application during run-time, through netbeans window ? or through any dialog box ??

I know there is an option to add parameters through the project property window, but it does not help to add run-time inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Define an input stream like this:

```
BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); //input buffer
```

and then use it to take command-line input like this:

```
a=b.readLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to do this in "netbeans" but to java programs you can provide inputs in this ways:

1. read file
2. read standard input
3. use swing components which read input
4. to only debugging purpose: use debug mode and breakpoint to stop and change any variables